# Extract file from gzip folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, gzip

I am trying extract the XML file from the gzip that comes out of clicking the button "SEC Investment Adviser Report" at the website [here](https://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/InvestmentAdviserData.aspx) (FYI, this links to the SEC website). Below is my (minimal) code. I continue to get "embedded null character" or "embedded null byte", depending on whether I feed `gzip.open()` `.text` or `.content` from my request. Can anyone help me get this file loaded so I can access the XML?

```
import requests
import gzip

file = gzip.open(requests.get(r'https://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/Content/BulkFeed/CompilationDownload.aspx?FeedPK=39545&FeedType=IA_FIRM_SEC').text,'rt')
```

Comment: [`gzip.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.open) takes a filename. Also, IA_FIRM_SEC_Feed_12_20_2017.xml.gz from that link does not appear to be a valid gzip archive. It has HTML appended.

Comment: You could use [gzip.decompress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.decompress). Note my comment about the appended HTML, though. `gzip.decompress(request.content[:request.content.find(b"\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>") - 1])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[gzip.open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.open) takes a filename, not compressed data. You could use [gzip.decompress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.decompress).

The archive from your question looks malformed. Specifically, it has HTML appended for some reason.

The following works by only using the content before the beginning of the HTML:

```
import requests
import gzip

request = requests.get(r'https://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/Content/BulkFeed/CompilationDownload.aspx?FeedPK=39545&FeedType=IA_FIRM_SEC')

xml = gzip.decompress(request.content[:request.content.find(b"\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>") - 1])
```